# SQL: count all where has no relation with certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `cars`. Cars has a one-to-many relation to `tires` table. Tires has a column called `condition` which can either be "flat" or "pumped".

I want to do a query where I count how many cars that has no pumped tires left. Meaning that ALL tires has to be flat. In order for the car to be counted. How do I do that

I was trying something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "cars" 
  left join tires on cars.id = tires.car_id 
WHERE "tires"."condition" = 'flat' 
AND "tires"."id" IS NULL
```

But that does not seem to be exactly right...

Here is a data sample. The result should of cause be a count of `1`. Only car with id 3 has no pumped tires

```
# Cars
id        brand         model
1         Audi          A4
2         BMW           X5
3         Ford          Mondeo

# Tires
id        car_id        condition
1         1             flat
2         1             pumped
3         1             pumped
4         1             flat
5         2             pumped
6         2             pumped
7         2             pumped
8         2             pumped
9         3             flat
10        3             flat
11        3             flat
12        3             flat
```

**EDIT**
`condition` and `car_id` is indexed and there are millions of rows - so it needs to be performant

Comment: What if no tires at all exists for a car?

Comment: It should not be the case. However if so, it's okay if they are counted in too

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: You'd want to select the cars where there does not exist a tire record for which "condition" = 'pumped'.

Comment: Be aware that using `count` together with `join` will give you tire count, not car count. See jarlh's answer for the right approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily I would just:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   cars
where  not exists (select null
                     from tires
                    where tires.car_id    =  cars.id and
                          tires.condition = 'pumped')
```

If, however, you had an extremely small proportion of cars for which any tire at all was 'flat' then I would consider filtering the cars down first to a candidate list for which to check for no pumped tires.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   cars
where  id in (select distinct id
                from tires
               where tires.condition = 'flat') and
        not exists (select null
                     from tires
                    where tires.car_id    =  cars.id and
                          tires.condition = 'pumped')
```

You'd want indexes on (condition, car_id) *and* (car_id, condition) for the latter.

Another method which might be of interest is:

```
select count(*)
from   (
  select   0
  from     tires
  group by car_id
  having   max(condition) = 'flat')
```

Answer (score 1):

Count all cars that don't have any pumped tires:

```
select count(*)
from cars c
where not exists (select 1 from tires t
                  where c.id = t.car_id
                    and t.condition = 'pumped')
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty and not tested

```
select count(*) 
from cars,tires
where cars.id = tires.carid
and tires.status='flat'
and car.id not in (select distinct carid from tires where status="pumped")
```

Comment: No need for distinct in the sub-query. No need to join with tires.